# Return the digit with the most occurrence in a line of digits that ends with a dot C++

Tags: c++

> Return the element with most occurrence in a line of digits that ends with a dot (input by the user, such as: 124325329083437993247.). If more than one element satisfying the condition, return any of them. C++

I could find the number of most occurrences but could not return the element itself. Also, I just input elements of a line one-by-one not as one input... Any help is appreciated.

By the way, I am a beginner, so would like to know the solution with only elementary knowledge :)

````
char count_element(string s)
{
    int counter = 0;
    int arr[s.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i <s.size(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = i; j < s.size(); j++)
        {
            if(s[j] == s[i])
            {
                counter++;
            }
        }
        arr[i] = counter;
    }
    int M = arr[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        if(M < arr[i])
            M  = arr[i];

    }
    return '0'; //max occurred element is to be returned```
````

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Show us the code you have written yourself, and I'll show you how to fix it. It's much better when you have a question to show the code you have written already, because that way I understand what you are stuck on and can give you better advice. You will learn more this way than if I just wrote some code for you to copy.

Comment: @john Sorry, it is my first post on this site, so took some time to edit to add my code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
char getMax(const char* line)
{

    int count[10] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; line[i] != '.'; i++)
    {
        int digit = line[i] - '0';
        count[digit]++;
    }

    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (count[index] < count[i])
            index = i;
    }

    return '0' + index;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that was before you posted your code. Since you already have something, perhaps it's better that you just use this as reference in order to fix what you've already done.

Comment: Would suggest `for (int i = 0; line[i] && line[i] != '.'; i++)` to avoid reading beyond the end of `line` if it contains no `'.'`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: The question says that the input is "a line of digits that ends with a dot". If you wanna protect from input which could lead to fatal errors (and general undefined behavior), then there's a lot more to fix in my solution than just checking for the null character. For example, any non-digit character would yield undefined behavior on the expression `count[digit]++`. I think that **in the context of this question**, it is pointless trying to cover all possible inputs, because it is not the overall purpose here IMO (though that's subjected to opinion of course).

Comment: Users will always do the darndest of things. No dings for not doing it, but it is needed. You take `char *` and pass no count -- so the only things `line` can be is a C-string. In that case, failing to protect against reading beyond the *nul-character* invites *Undefined Behavior*. If a user can F' it up, a user will F' it up. Protect against the dumb user.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: You did not refer to my notion about the user passing a string with non-digit characters.

Comment: That would necessitate `isdigit()` which you correctly point out can result in a negative array index or index above bounds. Both are worth a note in the answer as the questioner is "a beginner".

Answer (score 2):

I started with the code you posted and modified it a little bit to achieve `O(1)` memory complexity and `O(|s|)` time complexity.
Take a look at that:

```
char count_element(string s)
{
    int counter = 0;
    int count[10] = {0};
    int max_occ = 0;
    char max_elem = '0';
    for(int i = 0; i < s.size() - 1 /* The dot */; i++)
    {
        int digit = s[i] - '0';
        count[digit]++;
        if (count[digit] > max_occ)
        {
            max_occ = count[digit];
            max_elem = s[i];
        }
    }
    return max_elem; //max occurred element is to be returned
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

So this code can be turned into working code quite simply, just change your final loop so that as well as working out the maximum count, you also save the character that has the maximum count.

```
int M = arr[0];
int C = s[0];
for(int i = 1; i < s.size(); i++)
{
    if(M < arr[i])
    {
        M  = arr[i];
        C = s[i];
    }
}
return C;
```

However your code is very inefficient, as Hagen and Mohammed pointed out you can do much better.

Also `int arr[s.size()];` is not legal C++. It's a variable length array (VLA) but in C++ array sizes cannot be variables, they must be constants. The correct C++ code would be `vector<int> arr(s.size());`. But as Hagen explained, you don't really need this array.

Answer (score 0):

Before improving the code, yo may want to revisit your algorithm. If the length of the input is `N`, you use additional space `arr` of size `O(N)`and then you use nested loops, i.e., a runtime of `O(N²)`.
In actuality, you need only count how often each of the ten digits occurs, so you should only need `O(1)` additional memory (an array of 10 integers) and a single loop (`O(N)` time).

Answer (score 0):

Following usage of some STL algorithms might be useful to you:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

char search(std::string const& str) {
    std::vector<std::size_t> occurrences;
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < str.find('.'); i++) {
        occurrences.push_back(
            std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), str[i])
        );
    }

    auto it = std::max_element(occurrences.begin(), occurrences.end());
    auto pos = std::distance(occurrences.begin(), it);
    return str[pos];
}

int main() {
    std::string str{ "124325329083437993247." };
    std::cout << search(str) << std::endl; // 3
}
```